# What is this 2x2 figure with a hollow base?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image: 2x2 lego figure with a hollow base]

What is this 2x2 figure called? I want another one but I don't even know what to search for. Is it something before minifigures? Is it even LEGO?

Answer (score 7):

I got some clues from my sister. It's not a boy, it's a girl. Basic Figure Finger Puppet Female (bfp001) from 1980's LEGO Basic set

[https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=4224c01#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=4224c01#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Comment: They can be ever so fun to put on your fingers.

Comment: I remember those from my childhood!